# #checkbox:checked ~ item does nothing in html webpage with css

Tags: html, css

**what I try to archive:**
I am trying to show/hide a mobile navigation bar in my webpage, dependent if a checkbox is checked or not.

The requirement is specifically to not use javascript, therefore I try to archive the same with css.

```css
#menuToggle:checked ~ #sub_navigation_wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="main_navigation_wrapper" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="menutoggle">
    <div id="sub_navigation_wrapper" > 
      <a href="#">
        <div class="fixedwidth">Home</div>
      </a> 
      <a href="#">
        <div class="fixedwidth">Informatics</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="fixedwidth">Projects</div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="fixedwidth">About Me</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <label for="menutoggle" class="menu_icon_wrapper">
      <img src="/images/menu.png" alt="Öffnet das Menü" class="menu_icon"/>
    </label>
  </div>
</nav>
```

A fiddle can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bechti44/au3gevp2/3/

Upon clicking the icon, the menu elements should disappear:
[image: before clicking menu icon]

[image: after clicking menu icon]

**Issue:**
Nothing happens. I can see the checkbox is selected successfully upon clicking the image but the CSS is not applied.
When trying to apply a css selector directly it works:

```css
#sub_navigation_wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bechti44/au3gevp2/4/

Any Idea what the Issue is or how it can be fixed?

Comment: Voting to close as Typo: capital t in toggle css id but small t in html: https://jsfiddle.net/bzu4n3qt/

Comment: yes, also saw that ... too fast for me ..  thanks Pete

Comment: @tacoshy I tried. "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You named your id wrong inside your css, it should be `menutoggle`, and not `menuToggle`, just copy this in your css, and it should work :

```
#menutoggle:checked ~ #sub_navigation_wrapper{

  display: none;

}
```

Also, unless it's for some school project, it's a very weird requirement not to use JS haha.